# How to generate Couldformation template in YAML format?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html

`aws ecs register-task-definition --generate-cli-skeleton` will generate a JSON template. Is it possible to generate a YAML template? Or do I need to take the JSON file and convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the current document, it does not support output as YAML.

- aws cli v1 document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-task-definition.html
- aws cli v2 document: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/register-task-definition.html